# Find в питоне, надо выдлелить все после find, не включая слово которое оно ищет

Tags: python

У нас есть строка, например .п,р,и,в,е,т
нам надо получить всю строку после введенного элемента от которого надо все взять(не включая этот елемент), **основное это как сделать с помощь find и :, не включая сам элемент**

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос и приведите пример, что должна выдавать ваша строка на ваш тестовый пример: ".п,р,и,в,е,т".

Answer (score 1):

```
x = input()
y = input()
print(x[x.find(y) + 1:])
```